# ul not taking 100% I want my Ul to occupy full height

Tags: height, html-lists

I want my ul to get the full height of the div but its not taking the divs entire height so I need to change the ul to take full height of the div

```
.header-wrapper {
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    background: linear-gradient(base.$secondaryColor, base.$primaryColor);
}
.top-nav-bar {
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background-color: green;

    li {
        display: inline-flex;
        list-style-type: none;
        color: base.$whiteColor;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background-color: red;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        cursor: pointer;
        &:hover {
            color: base.$blackColor;
            background-color: base.$whiteColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code

Comment: can you share codepen or codesandbox link?

Comment: Can you share a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all relevant UI code and CSS?